# Projection Problems when Displaying an Image on a Map with Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I have some satellite image data I would like to display using Cartopy. I have successfully followed the image example detailed [here](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/v0.5/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html). Resulting in this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
img_extent = (-77, -59, 9, 26)

ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
# image data coming from server, code not shown
ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extent)
ax.set_xmargin(0.05)
ax.set_ymargin(0.10)

# mark a known place to help us geo-locate ourselves
ax.plot(-117.1625, 32.715, 'bo', markersize=7)
ax.text(-117, 33, 'San Diego')

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()

plt.show()
```

This code generates the following image [image: wrong projection]

My problem is that the satellite image data is not in the PlateCarree projection, but the Mercator projection.

But when I get the axis object with

```
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator())
```

I lose the coastlines.

[image: no coastlines]

I saw the issue reported [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/72). But

```
ax.set_global()
```

results in this image:

[image: where is my data]

The data is not present, and San Diego is in the wrong location. Also the lat/lon extents have changed. What am I doing wrong?

**Post Discussion Update**

The main problem is that I had not properly specified the image extents in the target projection with the `transform_points` method. I also had to be specific about the coordinate reference system in the `imshow` method as Phil suggests. Here is the correct code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

proj = ccrs.Mercator()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))
extents = proj.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(),
                                np.array([-77, -59]),
                                np.array([9, 26]))

img_extents = (extents[0][0], extents[1][0], extents[0][6], extents[1][7] ) 

ax = plt.axes(projection=proj)
# image data coming from server, code not shown
ax.imshow(img, origin='upper', extent=img_extents,transform=proj)

ax.set_xmargin(0.05)
ax.set_ymargin(0.10)

# mark a known place to help us geo-locate ourselves
ax.plot(-117.1625, 32.715, 'bo', markersize=7, transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
ax.text(-117, 33, 'San Diego', transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

ax.coastlines()
ax.gridlines()

plt.show()
```

Resulting in this correctly geoprojected satellite image:

[image: correct image]

Comment: My Cartopy 0.7 broke after upgrading to Mpl 1.3, so i cant test it for you. But shouldnt you specify the coordinates of the data your plotting? If you dont, i think coordinates are assumed to be equal to the axes projection. So try adding `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()` to your plotting commands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally, try to always be specific about the coordinate reference system your data are in when plotting with cartopy (via the transform keyword). This will mean you can just switch projections in your script and the data will automatically be put in the correct place.

So in your case, the `plt.imshow` should have a `transform=ccrs.Mercator()` keyword argument (you may need a a more specific parameterised Mercator instance). If your extents are in Geodetic (lats and lons) you will have to transform the bounding box into the mercator coordinates, but other than that, everything else should work as expected.

NOTE: I'm going to go and update the [example](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/matplotlib/advanced_plotting.html) to include the transform argument ;-)  (PR: https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/pull/343)

HTH

Comment: Thanks, I added post discussion update with the correct code.

Comment: Great. Glad it helped. Nice plot :-)